# Need to create a key: value list of objects in a JavaScript Array to send to a web api

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can someone please point out what is wrong.  I have some code that produces a simple object and adds it to an array, but the problem is that the last value overwrites all other value

```
      let search = []
      let XMLSearch = { }
      XMLSearch.First =  'Bob'  
      XMLSearch.Last =  'Smith'                 
      search.push(XMLSearch)
      XMLSearch.First =  'Mary'  
      XMLSearch.Last =  'Smith'                   
      search.push(XMLSearch)
      XMLSearch.First =  'Joe'  
      XMLSearch.Last =  'Jones'                   
      search.push(XMLSearch)
```

I'm sending the search as the payload in an AXIOS post to a Web 2.0 API as a

```
     <Route("api/pmid_Impact/PostValue")> Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal data As List(Of XMLSearch)) As HttpResponseMessage
```

and it comes in as a List of

```
       Public Class XMLSearch
        Public Property First As String
        Public Property Last  As String  
       End Class
```

But everyone is Joe Jones.  So I am assuming that I am overwriting my object before it leave my JavaScript with the last value put in.  How can I fix this?  Thanks  I'm showing three names as a sample but I will really need to loop over hundreds to make the search payload.

Comment: Create 3 different search objects, you keep updating the existing one at each step.

Comment: add `XMLSearch = { }` before every `XMLSearch.First = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
 let search = []
 let XMLSearch = { }
 XMLSearch.First =  'Bob'  
 XMLSearch.Last =  'Smith'                 
 search.push({...XMLSearch})
 XMLSearch.First =  'Mary'  
 XMLSearch.Last =  'Smith'                   
 search.push({...XMLSearch})
 XMLSearch.First =  'Joe'  
 XMLSearch.Last =  'Jones'                   
 search.push({...XMLSearch})
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer that I was looking for.  Simply three little dots.  Thanks.  Glad to have you around